# How iterate through two array in a object using Template helpers in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, handlebars.js, this

My HTML resembles this

```
<template name="stop">  
   {{#each thumb}}

  <tr>
    <td class="image" ><img src="{{this.data}}"></td>
    <td>
     <center style="float:right; margin-bottom: 25%;">    
       <h2> Do you like this product? </h2>

       <h2>{{this.text}}</h2></center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

And this template refers to my template helper which look like this

```
Template.stop.helpers( {
        'thumb': function(data) {
            console.log(z);
            return tweetImages.findOne()
        })
```

tweetImage.findOne() outputs this

```
Object {_id: "1", data: Array[7], text: Array[7]}
```

I'm trying to iterate through each item in both of the arrays for each time the template run but instead all the 7 values for each array get outputted each time. I know the contextual variable this is need somewhere but I cannot work it out. Would anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findOne` returns only one element so your `each` only iterates one time.
You need a nested `each` to go through the `data` or `text` property like this:

```
{{#each thumb}}
  ...
  {{#each data}}
    //but you won't be able to get 'text' here
  {{/each}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

But as you can see you won't be able to access both data and text arrays with this method. Maybe you could modify the data returned by your helper so it has the following form:

```
[
  {data: ..., text: ...},
  {data: ..., text: ...},
  {data: ..., text: ...},
  ...
]
```

So you could do:

```
{{#each thumb}}
  ...
  {{data}}
  {{text}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

To rewrite your data you could use a `for` loop:

```
Template.stop.helpers({
  'thumb': function() {            
    var result = tweetImages.findOne();
    var newResult = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      newResult[i] = {data:result.data[i], text:result.text[i]};
    }
    return newResult;
  }
});
```

Comment: Would you know how to go about re-editing the structure of the data returned in my helper in that case?

Comment: I added it in my answer